# Можно ли проверить наличичие пакета в условиях компиляции в Lazarus?

Tags: pascal, freepascal, lazarus

Есть модуль, предназначенный для работы с различными типами данных, включая некоторый тип, добавляемый модулем из подключаемого пакета. Мне работать с этим типом, в дальнейшем, понадобится, поэтому я включил его поддержку. Однако, модуль я собираюсь выложить для дальнейшего использования всеми желающими, и не хочу, чтобы он строго зависел от этого пакета, так как другим людям завязанный на него функционал может и не понадобиться.

Поэтому вопрос: Можно ли сообщить компилятору *"этот код выполнять только при наличии пакета A"* и, если да, то как?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Видимо, как-то так:

```
unit PacketA;

{$DEFINE PacketA}
...
end.
```

В своем модуле:

```
unit Unit1;
...
{$IFDEF PacketA} ... {$ENDIF}
...
end.
```